# Clear Redis Cache on Spring Boot Application Startup

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching, redis

On application (spring boot service) startup, need to clear the Redis cache.

Redis is running in a different docker container with own volume mapping. Since it retains the old cache, the application picks the data from Redis cache instead of Database even after the application restarts

- Tried `@EventListener` for `ContextRefreshedEvent` and it is never getting called.
- Tried with `@PostConstruct` in ApplicationMain class, but it doesn't clear the cache.
- Tried using `@CacheEvict(allEntries = true)`, but still no luck

  @Component
  public class ApplicationStartUp {

  ```
  @Autowired
  private CacheManager cacheManager;

  @EventListener()
  public void onApplicationEvent(ContextStartedEvent event) {
      cacheManager.getCacheNames()
                  .parallelStream()
                  .forEach(n -> cacheManager.getCache(n).clear());
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: Have you verified onApplicationEvent is actually being triggered and you are able to get cache values in loop. ?

Comment: Do you see your cache name, if you print the result of `cacheManager.getCacheNames()`? It's possible the cache manager doesn't return any, on start up. As a test, try using `@PostConstruct` and `cacheManger.getCache("your cache").clear()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was successfully able to clear the cache with `ApplicationReadyEvent`. As the `CacheManager` bean is available by the time, the cache is getting cleared properly on startup

```
@Autowired
private CacheManager cacheManager;

@EventListener
public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
    cacheManager.getCacheNames()
                .parallelStream()
                .forEach(n -> cacheManager.getCache(n).clear());
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide me you cacheconfig class. I am implementing something similar to this and still facing some issue.

Comment: Are you getting all cached data, because cacheManager.getCacheNames() doesn't return cached data. How you are getting?

Comment: @senthil  `cacheManager.getCacheNames()` returning empty data. How did this work for you ? I have same code

Answer (score 4):

A simple practice to clear Redis DB at earlier life cycle stage. To config CacheManager @bean with argument RedisConnectionFactory passed in, calling flushDb() to delete all keys of the currently selected database before build up.

```java
 @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        redisConnectionFactory.getConnection().flushDb(); //Delete all keys of the currently selected database
        return RedisCacheManager.builder(RedisCacheWriter.nonLockingRedisCacheWriter(redisConnectionFactory)).cacheDefaults(RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()).build();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For the Redis cache manager, if you want to clear the cache on boot, I think you will need to initialize the cache manager with a set of names. See the [RedisCacheManagerBuilder docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/cache/RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder.html#initialCacheNames-java.util.Set-)

For example:

```
RedisCacheManagerBuilder.fromConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory)
                        .initialCacheNames(Set.of("cacheOne", "cacheTwo"))
                        .build();
```

Then you should be able to use `@PostConstruct` in you cache config class, for example.

```
@PostConstruct
public void clearCache() {
    cacheManager.getCacheNames()
                .parallelStream()
                .forEach(n -> cacheManager.getCache(n).clear());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I changed ContextRefreshedEvent listener to ApplicationReadyEvent listener, it worked properly

Comment: @Senthil Cool, thanks for posting your solution as well.

Comment: Without initializing cache names is it possible to clear the cache?